# Am I building my SQL cursor the correct way?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

My script below will use two external tables to fill two separate tables, but am not sure if I am using my cursor the correct way. If I am using it in a incorrect way please help me to correct the mistake.

// update 
It's for an oracle database (ORACLE SQL)

```
DECLARE
L_volg_no1 NUMBER;
L_volg_no2 NUMBER;

CURSOR c_gip IS

SELECT
    artikelnummer,
    ingangsdatum,
    grossiersprijs
FROM dc_RMSSID_GIP;

CURSOR c_gip_promo IS

SELECT
    artikelnummer,
    ingangsdatum
    promo_nummer,
    actie_grossiersprijs    
FROM dc_RMSSID_GIPPromo;

     BEGIN
FOR r_sid1 in c_gip
LOOP

SELECT daa_imp_rms_gip_seq.NEXTVAL INTO L_volg_no1 FROM DUAL;

INSERT 
INTO daa_imp_rms_grossiersprijs (
    volg_nr
    ,importtijdstip
    ,importstatus
    ,artikelnummer
    ,ingangsdatum
    ,grossiersprijs         
)
VALUES (
    L_volg_no1,
    SYSDATE,
    'N',
    r_sid1.artikelnummer,
    r_sid1.ingangsdatum,
    r_sid1.grossiersprijs
);

END LOOP;

FOR r_sid2 in c_gip_promo
LOOP

SELECT daa_imp_rms_prm_gip_seq.NEXTVAL INTO L_volg_no2 FROM DUAL;

INSERT 
INTO daa_imp_rms_prm_grossiersprijs (
    volg_nr
    ,importtijdstip
    ,importstatus
    ,artikelnummer
    ,ingangsdatum
    ,promo_nummer
    ,grossiersprijs 
)
VALUES (
    L_volg_no2,
    SYSDATE,
    'N',
    r_sid2.artikelnummer,
    r_sid2.ingangsdatum,
    r_sid2.promo_nummer,
    r_sid2.grossiersprijs
);

END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax looks fairly good but trust your testing more than my eyes :)

But more importantly; why use cursors for this task?  Two insert statements would do the same job and being set-based (rather than procedural) code is likely to perform better in most RDBMSes.

```
Begin
    INSERT 
    INTO daa_imp_rms_grossiersprijs (
        volg_nr
        ,importtijdstip
        ,importstatus
        ,artikelnummer
        ,ingangsdatum
        ,grossiersprijs         
    )
        select  (
            daa_imp_rms_gip_seq.NEXTVAL,
            SYSDATE,
            'N',
            artikelnummer,
            ingangsdatum,
            grossiersprijs
    FROM dc_RMSSID_GIP;

    INSERT 
    INTO daa_imp_rms_prm_grossiersprijs (
        volg_nr
        ,importtijdstip
        ,importstatus
        ,artikelnummer
        ,ingangsdatum
        ,promo_nummer
        ,grossiersprijs 
    )
    select 
            daa_imp_rms_prm_gip_seq.NEXTVAL, 
            SYSDATE,
            'N',
            artikelnummer,
            ingangsdatum
            promo_nummer,
            actie_grossiersprijs    
    FROM dc_RMSSID_GIPPromo;

    commit;
end;
```

Comment: +1, you beat me by 10 seconds. Using a cursor for this is not a good idea.

Comment: +1 beat me by 4 minutes. This is the way to go, although the commit is still dubious and might be moved to a level above.

Comment: Agree about the commit.  And there is no exception handling.  But I was trying to replicate the functionality of the sample.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't use your cursor well.

Cursor usages in SQL-Server can be found [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172595%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).
You can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) about MySQL cursors.
Cursor usages differ from RDBMS type to RDBMS type. Your technical question would be more specific if you would add the RDBMS you are using as a tag.
Algorithm for cursor usage:

- Declare your cursor and link it to a query
- Open your cursor
- Process the rows of your cursor by fectching its rows and handle them as you like
- Close your cursor
- Deallocate your cursor

Exact usages can be found from examples.

Comment: would it then be better to use two scripts instead of one? It's for oracle by the way

Comment: Looking at the code, Eve is using Oracle, not SQL Server. I added the necessary tag.

Comment: I didn't use Oracle since 2008, my anser is valid for SQL Server and MySQL. About Oracle I'm not sure.